# youtube api video search using php restrict adult videos

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube API to search videos from my website and I want to restrict users to search adult videos from my site. Is there any option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the safeSearch parameter, set it to "strict" to avoid mature content. E.g.:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football&max-results=10&v=2&safeSearch=strict

More info here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#safeSearchsp

Answer (score 0):

safeSearch is also supported in v3 of the API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#safeSearch